Why the sample() function in R can implicitly coerce string as numeric for argument?
I was practicing input validation when creating a function. Accidentally I noticed that the sample() function doesn't need input validation for the argument size when using a string "4" instead of a numeric 4:
sample(x = 1:10, size = "4")

And I can get the expected results without any warning messages:
[1] 10  9  5  7

I have read the help page of the sample() function, but didn't find anything explains the behaviour of implicit coercion.
To me (I may be wrong), the function itself also didn't have the step that coerce string to numeric:
> sample
function (x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) 
{
    if (length(x) == 1L && is.numeric(x) && is.finite(x) && x >= 
        1) {
        if (missing(size)) 
            size <- x
        sample.int(x, size, replace, prob)
    }
    else {
        if (missing(size)) 
            size <- length(x)
        x[sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob)]
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x12473bcb8>
<environment: namespace:base>

I am just curious if anyone can explain what happened behind the scenes. Many thanks.

sample is a wrapper function. It ultimately calls .Internal(sample2(...)) which is C code. From there functions look like randSample(int n, ...), so the size argument is cast to int there.

Basically,  the R-Core team does its best to implement DWIM.
